# Extra Space Required for Long Title

Tags: baposter

I am making my first poster with LaTeX and I have a relatively long title (3 lines) which I am trying to fit in the small space designated for the title. I was wondering if there is any way to slightly bring down the title (perhaps by pushing down all the boxes) so that I make some extra space for my title. Please see my MWE and image. Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}
\usepackage{relsize}        % For \smaller
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230}
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{186,215,230}

\begin{document}

\background{}

\begin{poster}{
    grid=false,
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol2,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    headershape=roundedright,
    headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
    textborder=rectangle,
    background=user,
    headerborder=open,
  boxshade=plain
}
{Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=false - unused}
% Title 
{\sf\bf
A Relatively Long Title I am Trying to Fit in This Surprisingly Little Space Despite the Fact that the A0 Paper is Supposed to be Large}
% Authors 
{\vspace{1em} Author 1, Author 2, Author 3\\
    {\smaller author1@plshelpme.com, author2@plshelpme.com, author3@plshelpme.com}
}
% Logo 
{}

\headerbox{Header 1}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 2}{name=definitions,column=0,below=problem}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 3}{name=acknowledgements,column=0,below=definitions, above=bottom}{
\lipsum[1-1]} 

\headerbox{Header 4}{name=density,span=2,column=1,row=0}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 5}
{name=degreeDistribution,span=2,column=1,below=density,above=bottom}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possible solutions. First, (as stated in the `baposter` [documentation](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter_guide.pdf)) there is an option called `headerheight` to set the header height, with a default of `0.1\textheight`. This can be set to a larger value:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}
\usepackage{relsize}        % For \smaller
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230}
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{186,215,230}

\begin{document}

\background{}

\begin{poster}{
    grid=false,
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol2,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    headershape=roundedright,
    headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
    textborder=rectangle,
    background=user,
    headerborder=open,
    boxshade=plain,
    headerheight=0.15\textheight,
}
{Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=false - unused}
% Title 
{A Relatively Long Title I am Trying to Fit in This Surprisingly Little Space Despite the Fact that the A0 Paper is Supposed to be Large}
% Authors 
{\vspace{1em} Author 1, Author 2, Author 3\\
    {\smaller author1@plshelpme.com, author2@plshelpme.com, author3@plshelpme.com}
}
% Logo 
{}

\headerbox{Header 1}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 2}{name=definitions,column=0,below=problem}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 3}{name=acknowledgements,column=0,below=definitions, above=bottom}{
\lipsum[1-1]} 

\headerbox{Header 4}{name=density,span=2,column=1,row=0}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\headerbox{Header 5}
{name=degreeDistribution,span=2,column=1,below=density,above=bottom}{
\lipsum[1-1]}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The class makes sure that the content area is filled with the remaining space, so the A0 paper format will be preserved.

Another option is to make the title smaller:

```
% Title 
{\smaller A Relatively Long Title I am Trying to Fit in This Surprisingly Little Space Despite the Fact that the A0 Paper is Supposed to be Large}
```

[image]

And a third option is to change the title.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Marijn. I really appreciate it!